# Regular expression for accepting email ids separated by semicolon with any sequence of space,enter key & semicolon

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to one write regular expression for accepting multiple email ids separated by semicolon.
It may happen that user press space or enter key by mistake after any certain email id and our regex should accept that as well.

My current expression is :

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.])+@(domain1|domain2)\.(com){1,25}(($)|(;+ *\n* *)|(\n*;+)|( *;+ *\n*)|(;+\n* *)||( *\n* *;+ *)|(\n*;+\n*)|( *;+ *$)|( *;+ *(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]))))+$
```

above regex is really not efficient in my case. As a beginner I have referred some solutions and combined those as per my understanding.

**expected Output:**

should match: abc@domain1.com<`space`><`space`>**;**<`enter`>abc@domain1.com<`space`><`enter`>;abc@domain1.com

**(sequence of space,enter and semicolon can vary).
No other special characters should be acceptable.**

Can someone please help me in this case??

Comment: Out of curiosity, what language you're working with?

Comment: A regex validating a single email may not be what you need. Split with `\s*;[\s;]*` and  validate each chunk with a dedicated method in your programming language. Or a regex if there is none. If your email pattern should match only very specific emails, like matching `^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@(?:domain1|domain2)\.com$`, you may consider something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@(?:domain1|domain2)\.com(?:\s*;[;\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@(?:domain1|domain2)\.com)*$`

Comment: @Zlatko I am working with reactjs, in which while filling form ,user should add email ids in textbox separated by semicolon,

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide a direct answer, but as the commenters say, you can split the string by your separators, then validate individual chunks. An example in JavaScript:

```js
function getChunks(str) {
  const separatorsRe = /[\s;]+/g
  return str
    // trim the whitespace from the start
    .replace(/^[\s;]+/, '')
    // trim the whitespace from the end
    .replace(/[\s;]+$/, '')
    // finally, split the rest by the separators.
    .split(separatorsRe);
}
function validateEmail(str) {
  const emailRe = /([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.])+@(domain1|domain2)\.com/i
  return emailRe.test(str);
}

// test cases
const validEmail = 'a@domain1.com';
const invalidDomain = 'a@domain3.com';

console.log(`Valid email is valid: ${ validateEmail(validEmail) }`);
console.log(`Valid email is valid: ${ validateEmail(invalidDomain) }`);

// test cases with separators

const splitBySpace = '  a@domain1.com    b@domain1.com  ';
const splitBySemiColon = 'a@domain1.com;;;b@domain1.com;;;';
const splitByNewLine = `a@domain1.com
b@domain1.com`;
const splitByAllOfIt =` a@domain1.com
b@domain2.com;; ; 
c@domain1.com
   ;; ;d@domain3.com
   
   `;
   
console.log('Chunks split by space:', getChunks(splitBySpace));
console.log('Chunks split by semiColon:', getChunks(splitBySemiColon));
console.log('Chunks split by newLine:', getChunks(splitByNewLine));
console.log('Chunks split by all and any of it:', getChunks(splitByAllOfIt));

// Now test cases for a validator function

function validateEmails(str) {
  const chunks = getChunks(str);
  for (const chunk of chunks) {
    console.log(`${chunk} is ${ validateEmail(chunk) ? 'valid' : 'invalid' }`);
  }
}

validateEmails(splitBySpace);
validateEmails(splitByAllOfIt);
```

Now, the validateEmails function is where you wanna expand a lot more, I think. E.g. you probably wanna check for duplicates. You might wanna just take the valid values, and report back the invalid ones, or you might fail the whole validation based on that.

You can adjust that to your use case.

**Edit:** the regexes themselves aren't exhaustive or properly checked, as stated in the comments. The purpose of the example is not a solution to the OPs problem, rather it's just pointing in one way they could perform their email validation.

Comment: have you checked your validation fot this input :
`a@domain1.com;ab@dom.com`
Just asking because It is returning true in my case.

Comment: The parentheses in `([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.])+` are superfluous. If you want to capture the localpart, keep them but move the plus inside the closing parenthesis. (As usual, this fails to match some perfectly valid addresses, and will accept some unacceptable or at least unreasonable ones. You want to accept `foo+bar` and probably reject `.`. Obviously, not an exhaustive list.)

Comment: No, haven't checked, I've just taken the OPs regex and went a bit further with it. It's a proof of concept anyway, just to point out the way they could solve the original issue. Please do improve the example code if you have the time and desire.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the solutions you have suggested.
I have managed to write one regex for my issue:

`^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.])+@(domain1|domain2)\.(com){1,25}(($)|(\s*;+\s*)|(\s*;+\s*(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]))))+$`

and then before calling validateEmail function, I have used trim() function to avoid all the spaces and line breaks and then pass that resultant data to validateEmail function.
It solved my issue in my case.

Thank you for the help!! :)

Comment: `(com){1,25}` matches `com` 1 upto 25 times. no sure it is what you want!